# Exclude a directory from Perl module release using Dist::Zilla

Tags: perl, dist-zilla

I have a subdirectory in my Perl Module root directory that I don't want to release.

I tried using "prune_directory" or "exclude_file" properties of https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Zilla::Plugin::GatherDir

I tried to specify the [GatherDir] section, but this conflicted as duplicate with @Basic, so in my `dist.ini` now I have (full file: https://github.com/telatin/FASTQ-Parser/blob/master/dist.ini):

```
[@Basic]
prune_directory = experimental
```

When building with `dzil build --verbose` i have all the lines like:

```
[@Basic/GatherDir] adding file experimental/scripts/my.pl
```

so the directory I wanted to prune is indeed added.

What should I do?

Comment: Can you show us the whole dist.ini please?

Comment: Example dist.ini:  https://github.com/telatin/FASTQ-Parser/blob/master/dist.ini

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `@Basic` plugin bundle cannot pass through options to the plugins it uses. So you must first remove the `GatherDir` plugin from it using the [@Filter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Zilla::PluginBundle::Filter) bundle, and then use `GatherDir` yourself with the extra options.

```
[GatherDir]
prune_directory = experimental

[@Filter]
-bundle = @Basic
-remove = GatherDir
```

Another option is to use the [@ConfigSlicer](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Zilla::PluginBundle::ConfigSlicer) bundle to modify the plugin `@Basic` uses directly.

```
[@ConfigSlicer]
-bundle = @Basic
GatherDir.prune_directory[] = experimental
```

(The `[]` in this case is because setting multi-value options through Config::Slicer requires the indication that it's multi-value. See [the docs](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::MVP::Slicer#CONFIGURATION-SYNTAX) for details.)

Consider the [@Starter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Dist::Zilla::PluginBundle::Starter) bundle, a modernized version of `@Basic` that allows `-remove` and config slicing options by default, as well as many other improvements and options based on modern Dist::Zilla practices.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I admit I'm shocked that a complex framework like Dist::Zilla makes this task so hard... #ignorancebliss